# I am unable to load CSV in python using pandas with Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I searched the entire forum to find an issue to tackle the below mentioned error. 
What I am doing :

```
from pandas import read_csv

filename = 'C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Python/Kag/Building_Permits.csv'

data = read_csv(filename)
print(data.shape)
```

I am getting the error which is given below.

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-12fa80c97065> in <module>()
      2 filename = 'C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Python/Kag/Building_Permits.csv'
      3 
----> 4 data = read_csv(filename)
      5 print(data.shape)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    447 
    448     # Create the parser.
--> 449     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    450 
    451     if chunksize or iterator:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    816             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    817 
--> 818         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    819 
    820     def close(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1047     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1048         if engine == 'c':
-> 1049             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1050         else:
   1051             if engine == 'python':

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1693         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1694 
-> 1695         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1696 
   1697         # XXX

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

OSError: Initializing from file failed
```

Comment: What is your OS version? What is your python version?

Comment: Windows 10. Python 3.6 32bit. I am encountering this problem for the first time.